# How to select the end of a dynamically-generated array and hide part of its content?

Tags: php, arrays, hide

everyone!

My website has a list of office contacts being dynamically generated via PHP (partial snippet below). As you can see, each list result/child has a name, address and, on a following div, a google maps frame.
What I'd like to achieve is to call **the latest result of the array and have that one NOT TO display the google maps div.**

I think I can probably call it with the "end()" command, but I'm not being able to wrap my head around the right way to proceed... Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Thank you!

```
  <header id="standardheader">
    <div class="wrap">
        <nav class="standardsubnav">
            <ul class="standardsubnav_list vanilla"><!--
            <?php include_partial( 'contact/citynav', array('class' => 'standardsubnav') ); ?>
    --></ul>
        </nav>
        <h1 class="standardpage_title"><?php echo $current->getHeadline(); ?></h1>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="wrap">
    <section class="">
        <ul class="list4 vanilla">
            <?php $contacts = $current->getChildren(); ?>
            <?php foreach($contacts as $contact): $settings = $contact->getSettings(); ?>
                <li class="item4">
                    <a name="<?php echo $settings['city']; ?>"></a>
                    <div class="link4">
                        <div class="link4_inner">
                            <h2 class="title4"><?php echo $settings['city']; ?></h2><!--
          --><address class="address4">
                                <?php echo $settings['name']; ?><br />
                                <?php if(isset($settings['address1']) && $settings['address1'] != "") echo $settings['address1'] . '<br />'; ?>
                                <?php if(isset($settings['address2']) && $settings['address2'] != "") echo $settings['address2'] . '<br />'; ?>
                                <?php if(isset($settings['address3']) && $settings['address3'] != "") echo $settings['address3'] . '<br />'; ?>
                                <?php if(isset($settings['address4']) && $settings['address4'] != "") echo $settings['address4'] . '<br />'; ?>
                                <?php if(isset($settings['phone']) && $settings['phone'] != ""): ?><a href="tel:<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $settings['phone']); ?>">t. <?php echo $settings['phone']; ?></a><br /><?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if(isset($settings['fax']) && $settings['fax'] != ""): ?><a href="tel:<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $settings['fax']); ?>">f. <?php echo $settings['fax']; ?></a><br /><?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if(isset($settings['email']) && $settings['email'] != ""): ?><a href="mailto:<?php echo $settings['email']; ?>">e. <?php echo $settings['email']; ?></a><?php endif; ?>
                            </address>
                        </div><!--
        --><div class="link4_inner">
                            <?php
                            $mapurl = (!empty($settings['mapurl'])) ? $settings['mapurl'] : 'https://www.google.com/maps/@' . $settings['latitude'] . ',' . $settings['longitude'] . ',' . $settings['zoom'] . 'z'; ?>
                            <div class="gmap4" data-gmap="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( '{"lat":"'.$settings['latitude'].'","lng":"'.$settings['longitude'].'", "zoom":"'.$settings['zoom'].'", "mapurl":"'.$mapurl.'"}' ); ?>">
                                <noscript><?php echo __('Please enable javascript to see the map.'); ?></noscript>


                <?php end($contacts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the $contacts array. Then in the foreach loop check if the element beeing currently in the loop is equals the items in the array, if it's equal to the items, it's the last element, then exit the foreach:

```
$items = count($contacts );
$i = 0;
foreach($contacts as $contact) {
  if(++$i === $items ) {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @AngelDeykov, but I'm not sure how this solves my issue...? The solution you provided is to select the "last child", is that it?

Comment: yes, isn't that what you wanted ? You said the latest result. But what do you mean by lates? If not last array element?

Comment: My bad, @Angel Deykov! I understood it now! I think this does solve the problem. Thank you for the assistance.